# How to create shell script that wait till a program finished and after finished show me the msg that now your program is dead

Tags: bash, bashrc

In shell script how to create the script that wait and check a particular program running or not  if running then wait till dead, after death of the program that script will show the msg that now your program is dead that's all, 
Example:
I am playing a game, now i want to create a script that finds my game is running or not if running then wait untill the game is to be stopped, as soon as game stopped that script shows me the msg that "now your game is dead".

Comment: If you run a command, by default the script will not run the next command until prior has completed. For example `sleep 5; ls` will cause the sleep to execute (5 secs) before the next `ls` command is executed.  You may need to clarify your needs as it seems the default as I read it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add information there. Please don't add additional information in comments.

Comment: Okay, i re corrected, plz go through it

Answer (score 1):

If I create a BASH script using

```
$ cat > blah
#!/bin/bash
read
ls
```

Make it executable using [`chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chmod.1posix.html)

```
chmod +x blah
```

Then run it

```
$ bash blah 
-- script has stopped as i type this, it will continue on enter
bionic                        focal-desktop-amd64.iso            kde_neon                                  zsync_disco.sh
blah                          focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zs-old     qa_query.py                               zsync_eoan.sh
eoan-desktop-amd64.iso        focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync      qatracker.py                              zsync_focal.sh
eoan-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync  focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync.old  siduction-patience-lxqt-amd64-latest.iso
```

The script runs and pauses waiting for the `read` to complete.  I type the text "*-- script has stopped as i type this, it will continue on enter*" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then and only then (when `read` has completed) does the `ls` command execute.

I could add a "&" to the end of the `read` line so it ran in the background and thus `ls` would continue without waiting.. but what you want is actually the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `ps` in a loop until your program runs. When it finishes the while loop exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

appName="appname"
appCount=$(ps ax | grep $appName | grep -v grep | wc -l)
while [ "$appCount" -gt "0" ]
do
  sleep 1
  appCount=$(ps ax | grep $appName | grep -v grep | wc -l)
done
zenity --info --title="End" --text="Now your game is dead."
```

Put name of your application instead of `appname`. After `done` put lines you want to have to display message. I used zenity for notification dialog. You can use something else like `echo` if you want to display message in terminal window.

Comment: echo "Welcome"
sleep 2
# Start the pubg game
am start -n com.tencent.ig/com.epicgames.ue4.SplashActivity
sleepn2

#monitor my game

appName="com.tencent.ig"
appCount=$(ps ax | grep $appName | grep -v grep | wc -l)
while [ "$appCount" -gt "0" ]
do
  sleep 1
  appCount=$(ps ax | grep $appName | grep -v grep | wc -l)
done
echo "Now your game is dead"

Comment: @Zames Smith: Your comment is pretty much unreadable. Did you want to ask something or just post your working script?

Comment: This may not work as advertised if other strings in the `ps ax` output contain the string you are counting. One workaround would be to use the script to store the count and then launch the app with the script and compare the current count with the stored count. Cheers!